# Slider images not working otherthen IE

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have applied image slider it is working fine in IE but not working in any other browser.
Following CSS is used on the image tag.

```
style=" font-size: 0px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"

#wowslider-container1  .ws_bullets div{
    left:-50%;
}
#wowslider-container1 { 
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    zoom: 1; 
    position: relative;
    width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index:0;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images{
    width:900px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
```

I have verified image shows in the browser for more detail you can see this www.stepstrade.com
Any idea why getting this?

Comment: Hmmm, W3 validator shows 101 errors: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stepstrade.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0. Might wanna check them out.

Comment: Hufffff i will resolve them later currently can you guide how i can fix?

Comment: You are using tables for layout and inline styles, two MAJOR no no's.  If you can strip out the offending HTML and CSS and put it into a fiddle you might get some better responses.  I can see the image slider fine from Chrome.

Comment: @All I resolved this problem by myself. I was using image name as ID and user enter the name with space due too space in ID it was not working as per my requirement i need to use image name as id. It might help to someone else who is stucked as like me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To force your site to display the way how it should appear in IE9, all you can do is adding following code in your meta area, usually in header.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```